# Tabs with Errai-UI

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I'm trying to figure out how to do "tabs" with Errai-UI.

For example if the tab selected is `#home` the `Home` template is displayed or if `#about` the `AboutUs` template is displayed.

I have this entry-point class:

```
@Templated("#home")
@EntryPoint
public class App extends Composite {
       @PostConstruct
       public void setup()
       {
           RootPanel.get().clear();
           RootPanel.get("rootPanel").add(this);
       }
}
```

AboutUs template

```
@Templated("#about") 
public class AboutUs extends Composite {  
       @PostConstruct
       public void setup() { 
           RootPanel.get("rootPanel").clear();
           RootPanel.get("rootPanel").add(this);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn on the navigation you should initialize Navigation component in the entry point. Every page should have annotation `@Page(path = "pageName")`.
Switching between tabs then is possible just by url appending #pageName or using special component (see below).

See an example:

Inherit navigation module

```
<inherits name="org.jboss.errai.ui.nav.Navigation"/>
```

Implement entry point

```
@EntryPoint
public class Bootstrap
{

    @Inject
    Navigation navigation;


    @PostConstruct
    public void buildUI()
    {
        navigation.getContentPanel().setWidth("100%");
        navigation.getContentPanel().setHeight("100%");
        RootPanel.get().add(navigation.getContentPanel());
    }

}
```

Implement a page

```
@Templated
@Page(path = "myPage", startingPage = true)
public class MyPage extends Composite
{
   ...
}
```

To add a "link" inside another component you can use the following inject:

```
 @Inject
 private TransitionTo<MyPage> myPageTransition;

 ...
 myPageTransition.go(); // load MyPage
 ...
```

Comment: With the @Page annotation, for example MyPage, it will load the MyPage.html right? for AnotherPage it will load the AnotherPage.html right?

Comment: The components are inserted right into root DOM element, so there is no page reload. So what is changed is that AnotherPage composite component is rendered in place of PrevousPage component. As in gwt you usually have only one entry point .html and then navigation occurs without redirect to another page.

Comment: When I do this, I get this error: org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.container.IOCResolutionException: no matching bean instances for: org.jboss.errai.ui.demo.client.local.App  --> where App is the one with Page and Templated annotation

Comment: Try to add @Dependent (`javax.enterprise.context.Dependent`) annotation. This will let IOC know that it need to manage this object.

Comment: As of 2.2.0.Final, you should no longer need to declare a scope (`@Dependent` or `@ApplicationScoped`) on all `@Page` and `@Templated` types. If adding `@Dependent` to App solves the problem for you, please let us know so we can fix it properly for the next release. :)

Comment: @JonathanFuerth thanks for the point! I am using currently 2.2.0.CR1. So that means I will have to make an upgrade and check again :)

Comment: The error is fixed by upgrading to 2.2.0.Final however my app still can't transition from WelcomPage to AboutPage...

Comment: Are you putting the navigation content panel into the DOM? When you call TransitionTo.go(), all it does is put the correct page widget into the content panel. See `Bootstrap.buildUI()` an Alexey's example, or check out the [reference guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Errai+UI+Navigation).